# How can I root my HTC Legend without erasing my data?

Tags: rooting, htc-legend, unrevoked

I want to root my HTC Legend but I don't want to lose my data on it. I have seen the unrevoked method for rooting HTC devices but it does not have a version specifically for HTC Legend. Would the HTC Wildfire version work or do I need to look elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

With rooting there is no guarantee that you won' lose your data, but in general it is safe. For rooting the HTC Legend it looks like the following is the best method:

1. Register with [HTC Dev](http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/) and unlock you bootloader
2. Get the ACS HTC Super Tools and drivers from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1343114)
3. Install the drivers
4. UnRAR the Super Tools
5. Ensure your phone has USB Debugging enabled
6. Plug phone into computer and run SuperTool.exe
7. Do options 1 and 3 (in that order) to root your phone
8. Download the S-Off file from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1290841)
9. Move that file to the htcsupertoolv3\root\ folder where adb and fastboot are
10. Open a command prompt and navigate to the root folder where you put the S-Off image from above
11. Run the following commands:

    `adb reboot bootloader`

    `fastboot flash recovery recovery-clockwork-5.0.2.0-legend.img`
12. You are now rooted with a custom recovery.

**Note: I don't have an HTC Legend and this is just a synthesis of research that I have done.**

Comment: I have already gone through all of the HTCdev bootloader unlock preocedures and it will factory reset my phone.

Comment: Sorry about that. As far as I can tell you need to unlock the bootloader to root.

Answer (score 1):

I finally worked out how to do this. I used Z4Root to gain root access and it worked perfectly. I was able to get the data I needed without any problems at all.

Comment: You may want to select your answer as the correct one.

Comment: I'm not allowed to until tomorrow.