# Where can I find the "hack4legend" or "Legend Downgrading Tools"?

Tags: rooting, downgrade, htc-legend

In my quest to Root my HTC Legend, I have run into many problems. Now I am stuck with the fact the I seem to have to downgrade my phone to a previous version of android before I can root it.

I have come across two guides:

- [The unlocker](http://theunlockr.com/2010/12/13/how-to-downgrade-the-htc-legend-to-1-31-so-it-can-be-rooted/)
- [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1082362).

The first tells me to download "Legend Downgrading Tools" and the other tells me to download "hack4legendv5.zip". The links in the guides are not working (or are sending me to some malicious looking download site). I can't seem to find them when googling for them either.

If there is another way to downgrade or root my phone, I'm also open to that (If an answer gives me another way, I'll change the title of the question to match).

The [z4root](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38418/how-can-i-root-my-htc-legend-without-erasing-my-data) app suggested here doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Have you tried Revolutionary or OneClickRoot?

Comment: @t0mm13b No I have not. I have however found another [guide](http://technologic101.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/tutorial-how-to-downgrade-htc-legend-from-android-v2-2-to-v2-1-100-working-with-hboot-1-01/) with another link to a bit less dubious looking download site. I was able to download hack4legend there.

Comment: I don't know about OneClickRoot but Revolutionary doesn't support HTC Legend. Neither does the Unrevoked tool. But I see you have found a link for the tool you were looking for. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a working link for hack4legend: http://www.mediafire.com/?w32aen59riz8qnn

It came from yet another guide: http://technologic101.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/tutorial-how-to-downgrade-htc-legend-from-android-v2-2-to-v2-1-100-working-with-hboot-1-01/